# Microsoft 365 - disabling autosave and touch/mouse mode in the Quick Access Toolbar [UPDATE]

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, windows-10-quick-access

I just renewed my MS365 software and I've noticed that when I load Excel or Word, "Automatically Save" and "Touch/Mouse Mode" in the Quick Access Toolbar pop up.  I'm able to uncheck both and they go away, but as soon as I reload either program, the two options pop up again.

I prefer to save manually to a disk/my computer and I use my mouse; is there a way to stop these two items from enabling themselves each time I turn on Excel or Word?

EDIT 12/15/2023: Microsoft has put in an update and now the "Automatically Save" and "Touch/Mouse Mode" can be removed and they won't come back after you reload.

Comment: How dare you try to do things for yourself! Microsoft knows best! The default options are _the_ options - none other are acceptable!! `</sarcasm>`

Comment: Love that answer...hey, if MS wants to pay my bills, walk my dog and deliver me dinner, I'm all for it :-)

Comment: I can't address Excel. How are you loading Word? Do you have the option checked to save to your computer by default?

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I don't use Word as often as I use Excel, but I do have "save to computer by default" checked off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First, turn the AutoSave off and set to mouse mode.

At the right end of the Quick Access Toolbar there is a drop down. Uncheck these two options.

[image: screenshot]

For more, see my page on [Modifying the QAT in Microsoft Word](https://addbalance.com/word/QATmodification.htm#PageStart).

Comment: That I do know; I've done it several times.  I'm just looking for a way for it to stop coming up or enabling itself each time I launch MS Word/Excel.

Comment: It turns out a lot of people are having the same problem; I'll just have to play whack-a-mole until MS gives another update.

Comment: It seems that [Microsoft have fixed this issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/quick-access-toolbar-not-getting-customized/91b4c0b0-432f-44d3-b122-20d643faaf91?messageId=f9d30f0d-0cba-4c1c-b27a-e162caa75e62&page=1#:~:text=We%20have%20the%20fix%20for%20this%20issue.%20It%20will%20begin%20to%20be%20available%20after%20we%20finish%20the%20validation%20process.), but it needs to finish the validation process first. It's best to update Office to the newest to check this issue.

Comment: @Emily - I've updated my Microsoft 365 and was able to get the Autosave and Touch/Mouse mode removed.  I will update my post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. :) @bjcolby15